# How can I fix Laravel comments policy not working?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using inertia JS.
I created a forum where you can manage your posts and comments (CRUD).

Normally, the one who can modify or delete his post or comment is the one who created it and the administrator.

I was able to set up a policy for the post but for the comment it does not work. I need your help to fix this.

This is my show function for post and comments

```
    public function show(Post $post, Comment $comment)
    {
        usleep(500000);

        $post->incrementReadCount();

        $updateableCommentIds = $post->comments
            ->map(function ($comment) {
                if (Auth::user()->can('update', $comment)) {
                    return $comment->id;
                }
            })
            ->filter();

        return Inertia::render('Frontend/Forum/Helpers/PostDetails', [
            'post' => PostResource::make(
                $post->load('user')->loadCount('comments')
            ),
            'comments' => CommentResource::collection(
                Comment::where('post_id', $post->id)
                    ->with('user')
                    ->paginate(10)
                    ->withQueryString()
            ),
            'categories' => Category::all(),
            'can' => [
                'edit' => Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('edit', $post),
                'commentEdit' => $updateableCommentIds
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

This's my comment policy

```
class CommentPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(User $user, Comment $comment): bool
    {
        return $user->is_admin || $user->id === (int) $comment->user_id;
    }
}
```

This's my vue file

```
<div
v-if="can.commentEdit.includes(comment.id)"
>
        //show me this if im the auther of this comment
</div>
```

I already tried but it doesn't work either

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $canUpdateComments = $post->comments->every(function ($comment) {
        return Auth::user()->can('update', $comment);
    });

    // Return the view with the ability to update the comments
    return view('posts.show', compact('post', 'canUpdateComments'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that I had a commentResource and just with that I found the solution instead of checking each time on the post not directly on the comment...

```
class CommentResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            ...
            'can' => [
                'edit' => Auth::user()->can('update', $this->resource)
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```